# How to send image from openCV to a Web API

Tags: python, opencv

I have a web camera and I can capture video from it as following:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) and 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What I want to do is to send the `frame` to an Web API (HTTP), receive the response image and show that image.
I'm new to openCV. Would you tell me how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (taken from a real project). Some parts (authentication, response validation) are obviously skipped. Hopefully it will give you a good grasp.

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
from six import StringIO
import requests


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) and 0xFF == ord('q'):

        frame_im = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        pil_im = Image.fromarray(frame_im)
        stream = StringIO()
        pil_im.save(stream, format="JPEG")
        stream.seek(0)
        img_for_post = stream.read()    
        files = {'image': img_for_post}
        response = requests.post(
            url='/api/path-to-your-endpoint/',
            files=files
        )

        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```